# Use if condition in where clause of sql query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that is:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT DepotIo.Depot2Guid AS Depot1Guid, Depot2.Title, NULL AS Depot2Guid
FROM DepotIo
 JOIN DepotIoDetail ON DepotIo.Guid = DepotIoDetail.DepotIoGuid
 JOIN dbo.GetUserDepot(@UserGuid) AS Depot2 ON DepotIo.Depot2Guid = Depot2.Guid
 JOIN Item ON Item.Guid = DepotIoDetail.ItemGuid
WHERE DepotIo.Company = @Company AND (DepotIo.Branch = @Branch)
```

But I want to when @Branch  is not null, comes to WHERE condintion part and when it's value is null, relinquish it.. Like this :

```
WHERE DepotIo.Company = @Company AND (CASE @Branch 
WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN DepotIo.Branch = @Branch)
```

what's true command ??

Comment: Can DeDepotIo.Branch be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `CASE WHEN` as follows:

```
(CASE WHEN @Branch IS NOT NULL 
THEN CASE WHEN DepotIo.Branch = @Branch THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
ELSE 1 END = 1)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

This is usually handled using `or`:

```
WHERE DepotIo.Company = @Company AND
      (DepotIo.Branch = @Branch OR @Branch IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, this should do it.
If DeDepotIo.Branch is not nullable. This will relinquish rows where @Branch<>DeDepotIo.Branch, but not when @Branch is NULL.

```
WHERE DepotIo.Company = @Company AND (ISNULL(@Branch, DeDepotIo.Branch) = DeDepotIo.Branch)
```